# randomly populating a quiz using javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how I can populate my jeopardy-esque quiz game with arrays, so I can have randomly generated questions. Currently I am setting my questions up like this:

Array reading as `Question ID | Question | Question Options | Correct Answer`

```
    var cat1question1easy = ["1", "What color is the sky?", "Red", "Pink", "Blue", "Green", "Bluecorrect"];
cat1question1easy.name = "cat1question1easy";

    var cat2question2easy = ["2", "What color is grass", "Yellow", "Purple", "Black", "Green", "Greencorrect"];
cat1question2easy.name = "cat1question2easy";

    var cat3question3easy = ["3", "What color is dirt?", "Brown", "White", "Turqouise", "Gray", "Browncorrect"];
cat1question3easy.name = "cat1question3easy";
```

Then I store them into an array for easy questions:

```
var cat1easyquestions = newArray(cat1question1easy, cat1question2easy, cat1question1easy);
```

Then I pull my random question for the 'question 1' slot by using:

```
var randomcat1easyquestion = cat1easyquestions[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]
```

Which brings me to my main question, if my html for my question looks like this:

```
 <h3></h3>
 <input type="radio" name="" value="">
 <input type="radio" name="" value="">
 <input type="radio" name="" value="">
 <input type="radio" name="" value="">
```

How could I populate it so it pulls my array's info so it shows as:

```
<h3>What color is the sky?</h3>
<input type="radio" value="Red">
<input type="radio" value="Pink">
<input type="radio" value="Blue">
<input type="radio" value="Green">
```

Is this a viable way to generate a random jeopardy board? or should I be looking at a better route?

Comment: This javascript array shuffle answer could help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Maybe I'm crazy, but you can't have hyphens in JavaScript variable names.

Comment: @zero298 you're right, I'm used to a writing in my company's specific serverside language, but the same structure stands.

Comment: 1. Why are your questions stored as arrays, rather than objects (which would be way more readable)? 2. I think you are looking for either some sort of templating engine or something to directly manipulate the DOM (which could range from jQuery to Angular, depending on how exactly you intend to do this)?

Comment: @UnholySheep This is just me trying to work through what I am wanting to do. i've actually never worked with JS objects, but basically we are using an API where on submission of this (game) form, the ids all have to match their corresponding question. JS Objects seems like a way better way to write out my questions though, then just storing them in an array for each side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose to use a different data structure for storing your questions and answers:

```
var questions = [{
    question: "What color is the sky?",
    answers: ["Blue", "Red", "Pink", "Green"]
}, {
    question: "What color is grass?",
    answers: ["Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Black"]
}, {
    question: "What color is dirt?",
    answers: ["Brown", "White", "Turqouise", "Gray"]
}];
```

In this structure you would put the correct answer always first. When actually displaying the options you would first shuffle them. This has two advantages:

- You don't have to separately mention what the correct answer is in your data structure
- The user will get the options in a random order, which may be different the next time

Also, you might not need to actually mention the question number. The position of the question in the overall array defines the number.

Your HTML would need to have labels for the answers as well:

```
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="a1"><label for="a1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="a2"><label for="a2"></label>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="a3"><label for="a3"></label>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="a4"><label for="a4"></label>
```

The content of those labels show the answers to the user.

Here is working code:

```js
// List of questions. First mentioned answer is correct one.
var questions = [{
    question: "What color is the sky?",
    answers: ["Blue", "Red", "Pink", "Green"]
}, {
    question: "What color is grass?",
    answers: ["Green", "Yellow", "Purple", "Black"]
}, {
    question: "What color is dirt?",
    answers: ["Brown", "White", "Turqouise", "Gray"]
}];

// Generic function to return a shuffled array:
function shuffled(arr) {
    arr = arr.slice(); // shallow copy
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - i)) + i;
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]; // swap
    }
    return arr;
}

// define variables for some of the HTML elements:
var domQuestion = document.querySelector('#question');
var domAnswers = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[name=answer]'));
var domNext = document.querySelector('#next');

function displayQuestion() {
    // get a random order for the answers:
    var answers = shuffled(questions[questionId].answers);
    // Display question
    domQuestion.textContent = (questionId+1) + '. ' + 
                              questions[questionId].question;
    domAnswers.forEach(function (input, i){
        // Set checkbox value and unselect it
        input.value = answers[i];
        input.checked = false;
        // Display the answer text
        input.nextElementSibling.textContent = answers[i];
    });
}

// Initialise and display first question
var questionId = 0;
var correctAnswers = 0;
displayQuestion();

// Respond to a click on the Next button 
domNext.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // update correct answer counter:
    var domAnswer = domAnswers.find(input => input.checked);
    if (!domAnswer) return; // nothing was selected
    // update number of correctly answered questions:
    if (domAnswer.value == questions[questionId].answers[0]) correctAnswers++;
    // next question
    questionId++;
    if (questionId >= questions.length) {
        alert('You have answered ' + correctAnswers + 
              ' of ' + questions.length + ' questions correctly.');
        // restart
        questionId = 0;
        correctAnswers = 0;
    }
    displayQuestion();
});
```

```html
<h3 id="question"></h3>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="a1"><label for="a1"></label>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="a2"><label for="a2"></label>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="a3"><label for="a3"></label>
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="" id="a4"><label for="a4"></label>
<p>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. You have numerous mistake in code like reference to non existent array

```
var cat1question1easy = ["1", "What color is the sky?", "Red", "Pink", "Blue", "Green", "Bluecorrect"];
cat1question1easy.name = "cat1question1easy";

var cat1question2easy = ["2", "What color is grass", "Yellow", "Purple", "Black", "Green", "Greencorrect"];
cat1question2easy.name = "cat1question2easy";

var cat1question3easy = ["3", "What color is dirt?", "Brown", "White", "Turqouise", "Gray", "Browncorrect"];
cat1question3easy.name = "cat1question3easy";

var cat1easyquestions = new Array(cat1question1easy, cat1question2easy, cat1question3easy);
```

Loop through the array to create input radio

```
var randomcat1easyquestion = cat1easyquestions[Math.floor(Math.random() * cat1easyquestions.length)]
// create h3
var createH3 = document.createElement('h3');
createH3.textContent = randomcat1easyquestion[1]
// append it to dom element
document.getElementById('holder').appendChild(createH3);
// start looping from 2nd element as first two elemnts are not color
  for (var i = 2; i <= randomcat1easyquestion.length; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "radio"; // type of input
  input.name = "color"; // name is required for radio
  input.value = randomcat1easyquestion[i]; // assign value like red, blue, etc
  input.id = 'col_' + i;
  var label = document.createElement('label'); // label require for radi
  label.for = 'col_' + i;
  label.textContent = randomcat1easyquestion[i];
  document.getElementById('holder').appendChild(input);// append to dom
  document.getElementById('holder').appendChild(label) // append to dom
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2gk6qbLo/2/)